# Cloudformation awssdk InsufficientCapabilitiesException: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_IAM]

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

package.json

```
{
  "name": "env",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": ".history",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "manual": "node manual.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.209.0",
    "commander": "^2.15.0",
    "deepmerge": "^2.1.0"
  }
}
```

The following code

```
 try {
      await cloudFormationService
        .createStack({
          StackName: fullStackName,
          TemplateBody: merged
        })
        .promise();
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
```

Results with the following error

```
(node:7452) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): InsufficientCapabilitiesException: Requires capabilities : [CAPABILITY_IAM]
(node:7452) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
```

Once I add capabilities according to this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html

```
try {
  await cloudFormationService
    .createStack({
      StackName: fullStackName,
      TemplateBody: merged,
      Capabilities: [
        CAPABILITY_IAM
      ]
    })
    .promise();
} catch (e) {
  throw e;
}
```

I get results with the following error

```
(node:11840) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ReferenceError: CAPABILITY_IAM is not defined
(node:11840) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: It's supposed to be an array of strings, so `[ 'CAPABILITY_IAM' ]` rather than `[ CAPABILITY_IAM ]`

Comment: It might need CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html

Answer (score 0):

As per the AWS docs, **If you have IAM resources with custom names, you must specify CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM**. [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_CreateStack.html)

```
try {
      await cloudFormationService
        .createStack({
          StackName: fullStackName,
          TemplateBody: merged,
          Capabilities: [
            "CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"
          ]
        })
        .promise();
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
```